# C++ template overload call

Tags: c++, function, templates, call, overloading

I am trying to implement an execution pattern which takes any function and executes it with its own conditions/preparations. Regardless of this being a useful thing to do, it just doesn't work. It seems i can't access the template overload of the "Execute"-function (called in "main").

Specifically: Why can't i call the overloaded template function of Execute?

This is the full program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <functional>

class TransparentFunctionWrapper
{
public:
    virtual void Execute(std::function<void()> executeFunction) = 0;

    template<class C>
    C Execute(std::function<C(void)> executeFunction) // template-overload of the abstract function which will implicitly call it
    {
        C ret;
        Execute( // calls the abstract function with a lambda function as parameter
        [ret, executeFunction](void) -> C       // lambda declaraction
        {                                       //
            ret = executeFunction;              // lambda body
        });                                     // 
        return ret;
    }
};

class ExampleExecutor : public TransparentFunctionWrapper
{
public:
    virtual void Execute(std::function<void()> executeFunction)
    {
        printf("executed before.");
        executeFunction();
        printf("executed after.");
    }
};

void DoStuff() {}
int ReturnStuff() { return -5; }

int main()
{
    ExampleExecutor executor;

    executor.Execute(DoStuff);
    int i = executor.Execute<int>(ReturnStuff);     // Why does this not work? ERROR: "type name is not allowed"

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Visual Studio marks

```
Execute<int>(ReturnStuff) // "int" is marked as Error: type name is not allowed
```

The compilation puts out the error

```
"type 'int' unexpected"
```

Thanks to everyone willing to help!

Comment: Caution: `ret` is captured by value into your lambda. This won't compile because you're trying to assign it in the body without the lambda being mutable, and wouldn't do what you want anyway. Capture by reference with `[&]`.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i was actually debugging this in exact this moment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExampleExecutor::Execute` is not overriding `TransparentFunctionWrapper::Execute`, and it is hiding it in the `executor.Execute<int>` call.

You must explicitly call `TransparentFunctionWrapper::Execute`, as it is hidden by `ExampleExecutor::Execute`. Here's a possible way of doing that:

```
int i = executor.TransparentFunctionWrapper::Execute<int>(ReturnStuff);
```

[**live example on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c314c277baca7b1)

Comment: thank you very much!
do you know a way to expose the "Execute" through the "ExampleExecutor" class?
calling it with "executor.TransparentFunctionWrapper::Execute<int>" is rather unhandy. :P

Comment: @Oachkatzl: you could provide a wrapper **with a different name** *(e.g. `ExecuteBase`)* in `ExampleExecutor` that calls `TransparentFunctionWrapper::Execute`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! strangely enough, if i rename the "Execute(function<C(void)>)" into "ExecuteWithReturn" the "ExampleExecutor" doesn't hide it. This doesn't really satisfy me as i wanted to overload it to make it clear they are basically doing the same thing but i guess that's as good as it will get.